# How to replace dataAdapter with dataReader to fill data in a DataSet in my crystal reports C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset, dataadapter

Like you Know the easier way to fill a dataset is with a dataAdapter like this : 
DataSetEmp myDataSet = new DataSetEmp();
...(here Id did a select request..)

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = myCommand1;
adapter.Fill(myDataSet.myDataTable1);
```

AND
......(here Id did a select request..)

```
 SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
  adapter2.SelectCommand = myCommand2;
  adapter2.Fill(myDataSet.myDataTable2);
```

//I have a Crystal report

```
CrystalReport1 report1 = new CrystalReport1();
report1.setDataSource(myDataSet);
```

This Way works perfectly good, but I want to fill data with DataReader not DataAdapter because I want to Check some values In a while(myReader.read()){ ....} loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to populate the `DataTable` manually using its methods and properties. Eg. creating each contained `DataTable` in turn (in essence re-creating the implementation of `DataAdapter.Fill`).

Alternately you could use the `DataAdapter` and before passing it to Crystal Reports use those same members to modify the `DataTable`'s content.

Comment: You're right man, Creating a dataTable in C# code is a better way I think , thx.